# Exercise Multicomposition , functions in list

Tags: list, haskell, function-composition

This is an exercise:

```
-- Ex 12: recall the binary function composition operation
-- (f . g) x = f (g x). In this exercise, your task is to define a function
-- that takes any number of functions given as a list and composes them in the
-- same order than they appear in the list.
--
-- Examples:
--   multiCompose [] "foo" ==> "foo"
--   multiCompose [] 1     ==> 1
--   multiCompose [(++"bar")] "foo" ==> "foobar"
--   multiCompose [reverse, tail, (++"bar")] "foo" ==> "raboo"
--   multiCompose [(3*), (2^), (+1)] 0 ==> 6
--   multiCompose [(+1), (2^), (3*)] 0 ==> 2
```

As beginner, I am not able to solve that.
I tried many approach, this one does not work :

```
multiCompose [] = (1*) $
multiCompose fs = (multiCompose (init fs)) (last fs) $
```

Following my current understanding, it should work since it can be developed as follow :

```
multicompose [(+1), (2^), (3*)] = multiCompose [(+1), (2^)]           (3*) $ 
                                = multiCompose [(+1)]         (2^) $  (3*) $ 
                                = multiCompose []     (+1) $  (2^) $  (3*) $ 
                                =              (1*) $ (+1) $  (2^) $  (3*) $
```

My questions

1. Could you help me with a valid answer to this exercise ?
2. Could you help me to understand why my solution does not work ?

Thank you so much

Comment: First of all, `(1*)` is not a very good identity function, since it only works on numbers. Use the actual identity function `id`. Second of all, you can't just throw around operators willy-nilly like that, as Haskell functions are *not* just text replacement. Take a look at [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) for ideas on how to do this properly.

Comment: Thank you so much,  I found your remark about (id) function clever and it worked ! 
I tried to implement it without foldr as it was out of the lecture related to this exercise (but you did not know ofc)
Solution : 
multiCompose [] = (id)
multiCompose fs = (multiCompose (init fs)) . last fs

Comment: don't use `init`. instead of `[a,b,c,d] = [a,b,c] ++ [d]`, use the identity `[a,b,c,d] = [a] ++ [b,c,d]`.

Comment: It might help to think of `multicompose` in terms of the existing composition operator `(.)`, rather than explicit function application. Then the definition practically writes itself.

Comment: @chepner `foldr ($) ...` is just as good a route to go by. :)

Comment: Also, function composition is associative. You can muticompose the *tail*, then compose that with the head, which is a more natural way to decompose a list than using `init` and `last`.

Comment: @WillNess Sure, you are familiar with `foldr`, which the OP doesn't appear to be yet.

Comment: @chepner OK so scratch the `foldr` in what I wrote. :)

Comment: (Oh, I meant to write "Sure, if you are familiar ... ". I guess the comment means more or less the same with or without, but the tone changes.)

Comment: @lt512 if my answer doesn't help you with the additional understanding, don't hesitate to ask about what exactly is unclear to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot the argument, and one more `$`:

```
     multicompose [(+1), (2^), (3*)]          $ x
-- = multiCompose [(+1), (2^)]           (3*) $ x
--                               here |
   = multiCompose [(+1), (2^)]        $  (3*) $ x
   = multiCompose [(+1)]      $  (2^) $  (3*) $ x
   = multiCompose []   $ (+1) $  (2^) $  (3*) $ x
   =                     (+1) $  (2^) $  (3*) $ x
```

Instead of `[a,b,c,d] = [a,b,c] ++ [d]`, use the identity `[a,b,c,d] = [a] ++ [b,c,d] = a : [b,c,d]`:

```
   =   (+1) $ (2^) $ (3*) $                     x
   =   (+1) $ (2^) $ (3*) $ multiCompose [  ] $ x
   =   (+1) $ (2^) $ multiCompose [     (3*)] $ x
   =   (+1) $ multiCompose [     (2^),  (3*)] $ x
```

You can take it from here. In particular, `multiCompose [] x = x` must hold, and is a valid definition for the `[]` argument case.